# Java getResourceAsStream JAR inside WAR

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I have a Java webapp WAR file that depends on multiple jars in it's WEB-INF\lib directory. One of these JARS needs to load some config files by doing `class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`. However the InputStream resturns null. Is there a problem with taking this approach when the JAR is inside a WAR? The app is deployed on Tomcat6.

EDIT MORE INFO:

I'm tring to load in SQL queries from files so I can run them. These are located in a separate DAO jar within the web app's WAR, under WEB-INF/lib

```
mywebapp.war
        -- WEB-INF
          -- lib
             -- mydao.jar
               ---- com/companyname/queries
                   -- query1.sql
                   -- query2.sql
                   -- query3.sql
                   ...
```

CODE USING TO LOAD CLASSES

```
public class QueryLoader {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(QueryLoader.class.getName());

public String loadQuery(String fileName) {
  final String newline = "\n";

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(         
        QueryLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
              "/com/companyname/queries/" + fileName)));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  try {
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(newline);
     }
  } catch (IOException e) {
     LOGGER.error(e);
  }
```

I have also tried changing the getResourceAsStream line to

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
```

without success.

My development environment is MS Windows Vista and but I encounter the same error when running it on this environment and on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get it to work by using Spring's resource loader instead

```
public String loadQuery(String fileName) {
  final String newline = "\n";

  ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
  Resource res = ctx.getResource("classpath:/com/msi/queries/" + fileName);
  BufferedReader reader;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  try {
     reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.getInputStream()));
     String line;

     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(newline);
     }
  } catch (IOException e) {
     LOGGER.error(e);
  }

  return sb.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not making the rookie mistake of putting `QueryLoader` in a different JAR, the only problem I can see is that you're using `File.separator` yet appear (from your use of `\`) to be using Windows. When using `getResourceAsStream`, the separator is *always* a forward slash (`/`) just as if you're using a URL.

If I change that I get this:

```
QueryLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
          "/com/companyname/queries/" + fileName)
```

Of course, if `QueryLoader` is in the `com.companyname.queries` package (along with the queries themselves) then you should simply do this:

```
QueryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

Simple as that. (It's documented that [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) qualifies relative filenames with the name of the containing package.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish it had fixed my problem but it hasn't

Comment: Sounds like you need to turn on the JVM's class loader logging. Produces lots of output, but can be useful in obscure cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, but you need to take care that you use the correct class loader.

Comment: I have had trouble with the class loader in a old project, since that used a ClassX.class.getClassLoader() - (Where ClassX is most, but not nessesary, within the specific jar) since than i do not have had the problem anymore - But this is only how it worked for me.

Comment: You can ensure a correct classloader by getting the classloader from some class that you know is in the same JAR file as the resource you want to load.

Comment: @Neeme Praks, yes that's what I've got at the moment but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: are you sure there are no other copies of that class somewhere, in some other JAR? if yes, then could you describe a bit more about the specific configuration you have - where is the resource located, what else is located in that JAR, how are you reading that resource (code sample), etc. Add that extra description to original question, not to the comments here.

Comment: I think that it isn't whether it is the correct classloader, but what it is being asked to load. With the wrong slashes, it just won't work.