# PrimeFaces and JasperReports

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, jasper-reports, primefaces

i'm trying to develop a web app for reporting, and have built a site with EJB3 + primefaces already. Now i'm head aching how to integrate Jasperreport into primefaces... I found no guide or discussion about this topic, I wonder is it not possible? or actually it is not a right way to do? I'm actually quite new to develop JavaEE6, dont plan to use frameworks like spring and seam yet.

---

**model**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BookEJB {
    // @Override
    public void printReport() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, JRException, SQLException {
        Connection connection;
        Map parameterMap = new HashMap();

        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ctx
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();

        InputStream reportStream = ctx.getExternalContext()
                .getResourceAsStream("reports/report1.jasper");

        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookdb?user=root&password=******");

        ctx.responseComplete();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, parameterMap, connection);

        connection.close();
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();

    }
}
```

---

**Controller**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bookCtrl")
@RequestScoped
public class BookController {

    @EJB
    private BookEJB bookEJB;

    public void doPrintReport() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, JRException, SQLException {
        bookEJB.printReport();
    }
}
```

---

**view (JSF)**

```
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:outputText value="Click on the link below to generate the report." />
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="#{bookCtrl.doPrintReport}" value="Generate Report" />
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
```

---

**Jasper**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     *
FROM
     `book` book]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[title]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[price]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{Id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

---

The error occurred when I click the button of JSF, below log is from glassfish

```
WARNING: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB BookEJB method public void blah.BookEJB.printReport() throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException,java.io.IOException,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException,java.sql.SQLException
javax.ejb.EJBException.....

SEVERE: javax.ejb.EJBException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)

WARNING: #{bookCtrl.doPrintReport}: javax.ejb.EJBException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{bookCtrl.doPrintReport}: javax.ejb.EJBException...

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException...

SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: #{bookCtrl.doPrintReport}: javax.ejb.EJBException...

Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{bookCtrl.doPrintReport}: javax.ejb.EJBException...

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException...

Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException...

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response.....

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response.....

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response.....
```

Comment: how to solve the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" issue?  i suppose it is glassfish problem rather than Jasper and Primefaces now...

Comment: Your EJB is throwing a NullPointerException and that is core of your trouble here. What's its stacktrace?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the p:fileDownload component inside your commandLink?

See: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf

That way, instead of messing around with responseComplete or having to make a separate servlet, you just have another controller/managed bean method that returns an instance of StreamedContent (primefaces class).

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the response after "responseComplete()".  Calling "responseComplete()" should be the last thing you do.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to deal with jasper-methods is to disable ajax in the `commandButton`/`commandLink`. Thats how it is possible to stay with the Jasper-conversion.

```
<p:commandButton title="EK Preview" icon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" actionListener="#{ctrlFiDoc.doReport_PC}" ajax="false"/>
```

There is no need to stay strictly to the `p:fileDownload`-element if its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this line is causing the issue:

> InputStream reportStream = ctx.getExternalContext()
>   .getResourceAsStream("reports/report1.jasper");

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284014/java-getresourceasstream-jar-inside-war)